# How to set up a IRC server that logs all messages?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, irc

I want to set up a corporate IRC server to use for project discussions.

How can I make the IRC server keep a archive of all messages that are sent through the server? I want the messages available for browsing (also preferably searchable) over HTTP (using Apache).

How can I set up such a service?

Also, it would be a plus if a user connecting to a channel on the server could execute some command in the IRC client to (say) get the server to return the last 24 hours worth of messages on that channel.

(I am an IRC n00b)

Comment: If you use an IRCd that's compatible with [atheme](http://atheme.net/) you could use a raw output module. Alternatively, connecting a pseudo-server could log all traffic (including private messages).

Comment: There's also [a patch for ircd-hybrid](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/ircd-logging/) which adds logging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the server side, but it's not hard to make an IRC client that connects to rooms and logs everything said in them.

Edit: Try googling "irc logging bot", there are several available, including some that produce html/xhtml logs.

Comment: This is going to be a lot easier than having the server do the logging, and the same bot can respond to commands to return the transcript.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded supybot (http://sourceforge.net/projects/supybot/). Will attemt to configure it to do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Inspire IRCd [supports logging everything](http://wiki.inspircd.org/LogTypes).